# Apache Block Ip address in LAN using Proxy Settings

Tags: php, apache, wamp

How can I block an ip addresses in LAN network which are using proxy settings.

I have an application hosted on our intranet using wampserver. I tried to block ip address using apache but its not working since all machines are by default behind proxy settings.

Is there any other way to block local ip address? Is it possible to do with apache ?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem/requirement is not clear.

Do you want Apache to deny any request coming via your proxy server while allowing others?

Comment: Not all requests. Deny based on their original ip address. Since the requests are sent from proxy server , the ip address in my logs are different. So i can't block them.

Comment: Definitely you can do it using PHP. `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` contains the client's IP address when the request is coming via a proxy server (`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`). If you receive a direct request, `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is the client's IP address. It may be possible with `.htaccess` file using Apache's `rewrite` module. Please refer to http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html. If I come across any answer I'll update you.

Comment: Amil, Thanks for your reply. Would you please give me more instructions how to include them in apache httpd.conf file ?

Comment: ^^ I meant .htaccess. Thanks for the hint. I'm looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at port forwarding.  In your router you have to forward all the incoming requests on your IP to the private IP of your PC.  If your real IP is dynamic, you might want to take a look at services such as dyndns or no-ip